# how to get the arrow keys on the keyboard to trigger navigation (previous/next page) links within a blog

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, keyboard, navigation

the script i've pieced together so far looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* KEYNAV */
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
if (! e) var e = window.event;
var code = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
if (! e.shiftKey && ! e.ctrlKey && ! e.altKey && ! e.metaKey) {
if (code == Event.KEY_LEFT) {
if ($('previous_page_link')) location.href = $('previous_page_link').href;
} else if (code == Event.KEY_RIGHT) {
if ($('next_page_link')) location.href = $('next_page_link').href;}
}
}); 
</script>
```

and my html looks like this:

```
<p>
{block:PreviousPage}
<a id="previous_page_link" href="{PreviousPage}">PREVIOUS PAGE</a> 
{/block:PreviousPage}

{block:NextPage}
<a id="next_page_link" href="{NextPage}">NEXT PAGE</a>
{/block:NextPage}
</p>
```

the {PreviousPage} / {NextPage} code represents dynamic page links which are different depending on which page you are on. this particular question is specific to tumblr, but generally as well:

is there a way to get my left and right arrow keys to trigger these dynamic links?

thank you for reading and any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This approach can hijack arrow keys for screen readers that use them to navigate through various page element. See: https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
function leftArrowPressed() {
   // Your stuff here
}

function rightArrowPressed() {
   // Your stuff here
}

document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            leftArrowPressed();
            break;
        case 39:
            rightArrowPressed();
            break;
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the `evt = evt || window.event;` about?

Comment: @MadsSkjern: That's for old versions of Internet Explorer (up to and including version 8), in which the event object is not provided as a parameter to the event handler function and is instead available as `window.event`.

Comment: Note in 2021: `evt.keyCode` has been deprecated for a good while, and you should instead use [.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) or [.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) to detect the key pressed. E.G: `case "ArrowLeft":` for the left arrow key.

Answer (score 6):

Use this to tell you the `keyIdentifier` attribute of the  object.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.onkeydown = function() {
  alert (event.keyIdentifier);
}; 
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you can use if-then logic to ignore all key presses you aren't interested in, and wire the correct behavior to the ones you are.

The following will assign the left and right arrow keys to your links (based on the id of the anchor/link elements).

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            document.onkeydown = function() 
                {
                    var j = event.keyIdentifier
                    if (j == "Right")
                        window.location = nextUrl
                    else if (j == "Left")
                        window.location = prevUrl            
                        }
                   });

      $(document).ready(function() {
                    var nextPage = $("#next_page_link")
                    var prevPage = $("#previous_page_link")
                    nextUrl = nextPage.attr("href")
                    prevUrl = prevPage.attr("href")
                });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    <a id="previous_page_link" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a> 
    <a id="next_page_link" href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `keyIdentifier` is not supported on most browsers (including the current version of Firefox), so is not suitable for general use on the web yet.

Comment: Thanks for the info Tim.  I only tested it in Chrome.

Comment: thank you very much for your help eric the effort was appreciated